# how to get the response message from cassandra (after successful data dump) to nifi?

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am dumping data from csv file to Cassandra after few data manipulation through NIFI.
I am expecting a response message from cassandra (inorder to make sure all data got dumped), once after this success/failure message I need to trigger one more API in a downstream pipeline.

Could anyone help me how to get the response message from cassandra ?

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question. Could you please elaborate on what processor you're using and how you're doing it in NiFi? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK none of the PutCassandra processors pass along a response from Cassandra itself, either the send/execute from the client (NiFi in this case) works or it doesn't, and usually the incoming flow file is simply transferred to success or failure accordingly. Unless you need some data from the "response", just having the flow file show up downstream should be indication of whether it worked or not.

If there is some necessary data in the response to the client, please feel free to open an improvement Jira to include it in the outgoing flow file (probably as attribute(s) so you can route on them later).